# JLex syntax error while recognizing comments

Tags: java, lexical-analysis

Following is a code snippet of a [JLex](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/java/JLex/current/manual.html) file, `example.lex`, which is used to recognize comments of the form `(*...*)`:

```
<YYINITIAL>  \(\*(([^\(*]|\(($|[^*])|\*($|[^\)]))*)\*\) {System.out.println("A comment.") ;}
```

It is the line 81 of the `.lex` file. The error that JLex gives is :

```
C:\JAVA>java JLex.Main example.lex
Processing first section -- user code.
Processing second section -- JLex declarations.
Processing third section -- lexical rules.
Creating NFA machine representation.
Error: Parse error at line 81.
Description: Syntax error.
Parse error.
```

But, the regular expression seems to have correct syntax according to [this](https://regex101.com/r/9QPYx6/1). So, the problem seems to be JLex specific.

Any hints on solving this problem are welcome!

**EDIT:** Well, it seems like JLex has a problem with `$`. For example:

```
<YYINITIAL> 5($|5) {System.out.println("A dollar.") ;}
```

Gives out the same error.
Whereas,

```
<YYINITIAL> 5$ {System.out.println("A dollar.") ;}
```

doesn't give any errors. Is this a bug or some well reasoned behaviour ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many regex libraries, `$` is a zero-length assertion indicating that the next character is a newline character (or, in some cases, the end of the input if the input is not terminated with a newline). Since it doesn't match the next character, if it is used in the middle of a pattern it would have to be followed by something which does match a newline (such as `\n`) and doing that would make the `$` redundant.

In JLex, as in the original Lex, `$` can only be used at the *end* of a pattern, which is really the only place where it makes sense. In your case, I'm pretty sure you could just write `[^*]` instead of `($|[^*])` (for example), since "anything but a `*`" includes newline characters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!